# How to click the element from the table Search by specific text

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

How to click on element search by text within table. I have tried some code but its not working.

HTML:

```
<td _ngcontent-c8="" class="align-middle cursorPoint" tabindex="0">Shelton</td>
```

I want to click on this `<tr>` which having text **Shelton** in it.

Comment: Your code is missing

Comment: i want to select with text shelton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate and `click()` the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath` 1:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='align-middle cursorPoint' and text()='Shelton']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath` 2:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[text()='Shelton']"))).click();
  ```

---

### Update

To achieve the same in a step-wise manner:

```
WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='align-middle cursorPoint' and text()='Shelton']")));
elem.click();
```

Comment: i used Thread.sleep(); but it not worked..anyway your code works thanks so much

Comment: i have another query,i want to store this value in variable new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='align-middle cursorPoint' and text()='Shelton']"))).click();     so i can search this text with entire table

Comment: @ArjunBharadwaj No, we are not **storing** the variable, rather we are locating and invoking `click()` at the same go. Check the updated the answer with steps.

Comment: yes i understood but how to check that text value through out the table

Comment: Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?